# Formation of folder redundantly

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, audio-analysis

I have the following [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1zAM.png). I want to iterate through sub folders (machine, gunshot) and process .wav files and build mfccresult folder in each category and the .csv file in it. I have the following code and the MFCC  folder is keep forming in already formed MFCC folder.

```
parent_dir = 'sound'
for subdirs, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_dir):

    resultsDirectory = subdirs + '/MFCC/'
    if not os.path.isdir("resultsDirectory"):
        os.makedirs(resultsDirectory)
    for filename in os.listdir(subdirs):
        if filename.endswith('.wav'):
            (rate,sig) = wav.read(subdirs + "/" +filename)
            mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)
            fbank_feat = logfbank(sig,rate)
            outputFile = resultsDirectory + "/" + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".csv"
            file = open(outputFile, 'w+')
            numpy.savetxt(file, fbank_feat, delimiter=",")
            file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of python are you using? Not sure if this has changed in the past, but `os.walk` does not return "subdirs" as the first of the tuple, but the dirpath. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.walk) for python 3.6.

I don't know your absolute path, but seeing as you are passing in the path `sound` as a relative reference, I assume it is a folder inside the directory where you run your python code. So for example, lets say you are running this file (lets call it mycode.py) from

`/home/username/myproject/mycode.py`

and you have some subdirectory:

`/home/username/myproject/sound/`

So:

`resultsDirectory = subdirs + '/MFCC/'`

as written in your code above would resolve to:

`/home/username/myproject/sound/MFCC/`

So your first if statement will be entered since this is not an existing directory. Thereby you create a new directory:

`/home/username/myproject/sound/MFCC/`

From there, you take

`filename in os.listdir(subdirs)`

This is also appears to be a misunderstanding of the output of this function. `os.listdir()` will return directories not files. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.listdir) for the man on that.

So now you are looping through the directories in:

`/home/username/myproject/sound/`

Here, I assume you have some of the directories from your diagram already made. So I assume you have:

`/home/username/myproject/sound/machine_sound`
`/home/username/myproject/sound/gun_shot_sound`

or something along those lines.

So the if statement will never be entered, since your directory names to not end with '.wav'.

Even if it did enter, you'd still have issues as`filename` will actually be equal to `machine_sound` on the first loop, and `gun_shot_sound` in the second time through.

Maybe you are using some other `wav` library, but the python built-in is called `wave` and you need to call the `wave.open()` on the file not `wav.read()`. See here for the docs.

I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve with the call to `os.path.splitext(filename)[0]`, but you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) You will end up with the same thing that went in in this case though, so `machine_sound` and `gun_shot_sound`.

Your output file will thus result in:

`/home/username/myproject/sound/MFCC/machine_sound.csv`

on the first loop, and

`/home/username/myproject/sound/MFCC/gun_shot_sound.csv`

the second time through.

So in conclusion, I'm not sure what is happening when you say "MFCC folder is keep forming in already formed MFCC folder" but you definitely have a lot of reading ahead of you before you can understand your own code, and have any hope of fixing it to do what you want. Assuming you read through the links I provided, you should be able to do that though. Good luck!

Additionally, you had quite few typos in your code that I edited, include the immensely important whitespace characters. You should clean that up and ensure your code runs before posting it here, then double check that your copy/paste action did not result in any errors. People will be much more willing to help if you clean up your presentation a bit.

Comment: am using google colab python 3.6 .while am using the code.so am saving my files by making a directory named sound in contents. The code is working but the problem is repeated formation of MFCCs again.i don't know  how i can put up the image of MFCC folder formation. Thanks for your support.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the answer via the check mark next to the answer. Otherwise, please let me know what my answer is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

```
for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(parent_dir):
 for folder in next(os.walk(parent_dir))[1]:
  resultsDirectory= folder + '/MFCC'
  absPath = os.path.join(parent_dir, resultsDirectory)
  if not os.path.isdir(absPath):
    os.makedirs(absPath)
 for filename in os.listdir(subdir):
  print('listdir')
  if filename.endswith('.wav'):
    print("csv file writing")
    (rate,sig) = wav.read(subdir + "/" +filename)
    mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)
    fbank_feat = logfbank(sig,rate)
    print("fbank_feat")
    outputFile =subdir + "/MFCC"+"/" + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".csv"
    file = open(outputFile, "w+")
    numpy.savetxt(file, fbank_feat, delimiter=",")
    file.close()
```

Here the csv file is stored in the subdirectory not in mfcc folder for each category.
I have issue with output path file.